# How to see elements down the ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

As I understand list view takes all screen size.

1. But how to make empty space for buttons at the bottom of the screen?
2. And also  how to see total sum text which is below the list?

Here is part of my xml file of fragment without bottom navigation.

- In Relative layout I have amount of services text, list of items, and total sum text.
- After Relative layout I have Linear Layout with 2 buttons
- Both of this layouts are in Linear layout

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/services_list_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/amount_of_positions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Amount of services: "/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount_of_services"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/services_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/amount_of_positions"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/services_list_view">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Total Sum:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_price_for_all_services"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirm"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

At image I put new item to list and after some number of items I loose my buttons out of the screen.

[image: problem]
Thanks for help, I changed my xml to new:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/amount_of_positions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Amount of services: "/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount_of_services"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/services_list_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_panel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/amount_of_positions">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/services_list_lin_lay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/services_list_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/total_sum_tv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:text="Total Sum:" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/total_price_for_all_services"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

                    </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Confirm"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Image of the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML layout, you are using `wrap_content` for `ListView`. If you use `wrap_content`, it means that the ListView will keep on increasing its height till it fits all the children. This will push down the bottom view as it's anchored to be at the bottom of the ListView. For `RecyclerView` or `ListView` it's best practice to set a fixed height. You can do it the following way.

1. Set a fixed height for the `ListView` - 180dp or something

Or

1. Set its height as `match_parent` and anchor it above the bottom view with `android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container"`
2. The Bottom container should be fixed at the bottom by `android:alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 1):

ListView does not necessarily take the whole height of screen.
Something you can try:

RelativeLayout
    Amount // keep the same
    List: use layout_above=“id/sum”
    Sum: remove layout_below, use android:align_parent_bottom=“true”

Sorry for the formatting, I am typing on my phone.